# Postfix server is sending non-delivery notifications with a blank "from" address

Tags: postfix-mta, mta

I have a Postfix 3.1.0 MTA that sends non-delivery notifications with a blank "from" address, like so:

`postfix/bounce[58637]: B85763E70B: sender non-delivery notification: F1F8A3FF94`

`postfix/qmgr[1861]: F1F8A3FF94: from=<>, size=41644, nrcpt=1 (queue active)`

With blank "from" information, many email systems block the NDN as well, which generates another NDN.

How can I fix this?